# AWS internal load balancer - unable to access using generated DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, internal-load-balancer

I need to create an internal website for a company accesible only through company's VPN. I have an EC2 instance with a webserver and I was able to access the website through instance's private IP. Now I'm trying to connect the instance to internal ELB and I'm facing a problem with ELB's DNS name.

Instance is added to ELB's target group, they are on the same subnet, it passes the health check, I'm able to send a request from browser to ELB using its IPs addresses but when I try to do the same with ELB's DNS name I don't get any response. Security groups are also correct.

I'm also unable to ping ELB's DNS name from EC2 instance.

Why internal ELB's DNS name does not work in the browser/postman? And how I can fix it?

Comment: can you access other services by DNS ? for example try to reach the instance by it's private DNS. It seems for me like your company did not configure setup a Hybrid DNS, so that your company DNS servers can resolve AWS DNS endpoints. This links should help you https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-dns-resolution-between-on-premises-networks-and-aws-by-using-unbound/

Comment: Try to request from another instance on your VPC, If It works the problem is your company's DNS. Also check if you can resolve the ELB DNS inside your company using `nslookup` or `dig`.

Comment: thank you guys, all answers are correct. The problem is, I can't change anything in company configuration, so time to request ticket... :) Please add one comment, and I accept it...